# Is there a better way to express the absolute error function in point-free notation?

Tags: haskell, pointfree

In pointful notation:

`absoluteError x y = abs (x-y)`

An unclear example in pointfree notation:

`absoluteError' = curry (abs . uncurry (-))`

Comment: If it's clear in pointy notation, then what's wrong with it? This looks like the sort of example where any point-free version is going to have to be read by mentally converting back anyway...

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Here's how you could derive it yourself, in small steps:

```
absoluteError x y = abs (x-y) = abs ((-) x y) = abs ( ((-) x) y) 
                  = (abs . (-) x) y = ( (abs .) ((-) x) ) y = 
                  = ( (abs .) . (-) ) x y
```

so, by [eta-reduction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Eta_conversion), if `f x y = g x y` we conclude `f = g`.

Further, using [`_B = (.)`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatory_logic#Combinators_B.2C_C) for a moment,

```
(abs .) . (-) = _B (abs .) (-) = _B (_B abs) (-) = (_B . _B) abs (-)
              = ((.) . (.)) abs (-)
```

Comment: Plus one for the previous help and perfect answer

Answer (score 26):

Here's a handful of ways.

1. the old-fashioned: `absoluteError = (abs .) . (-)`
2. use the so-called "boobs operator", or "owl operator" `absoluteError = ((.) . (.)) abs (-)`
3. name the boobs operator something more politically correct (and what the heck, generalize it at the same time)

   ```
   (.:) = fmap fmap fmap
   absoluteError = abs .: (-)
   ```
4. using [semantic editor combinators](http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators):

   ```
   result :: (o1 -> o2) -> (i -> o1) -> (i -> o2)
   result = (.)

   absoluteError = (result . result) abs (-)
   ```

Of course, these are all the same trick, just with different names. Enjoy!

Comment: Why isn't `.:` defined anywhere standard, anyway? Or is it?

Comment: @leftroundabout It's defined in several hackage packages, but it's such a tiny definition that most people don't feel the extra dependency is worth the effort, I think.

Comment: @DanielWagner: Is it? I couldn't find it anywhere.