# How can I elegantly do not . any in Haskell?

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to figure out how to negate the results of two parameter boolean function like `not . any`. I understand why it didn't work by breaking it down as shown below, but I'm not sure how to write a function that does this elegantly. I managed to do `curry $ not . uncurry any`

```
Prelude> :t not
not :: Bool -> Bool

Prelude> :t any
any :: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool

Prelude> :t (.)
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c

curry $ not . uncurry any
:: Foldable t => (a -> Bool) -> t a -> Bool
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a standard point-free-ifier, available standalone or via lambdabot, which gives:

```
18:02 <dmwit> ?pl \f xs -> any (\x -> not (f x)) xs
18:02 <lambdabot> any . (not .)
18:04 <dmwit> ?pl \f xs -> not (any f xs)
18:04 <lambdabot> (not .) . any
```

There are [many ways to spell this general operation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11006842/791604).

**Edit:** Thanks to [zudov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2081046/zudov) for the following suggested extra text: You can also access `pointfree` tool by installing [`pointfree`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pointfree) or using one of web interfaces (e.g. http://pointfree.io).

Comment: Thank you very much Daniel. I learned about pointfree from your post.

Comment: I put in `group (sort (map (toLower . pack) zs))`, and it suggested the exact same expression as point-free. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Yep, that's already point-free! You *probably* meant to ask it to point-free-ify `\zs -> ...` or similar.

Answer (score 6):

Define

```
result = (.)
argument = flip (.)
```

Then you want

```
(result.result) not any
```

i.e., negating the second result of `any`.

(It's also

```
argument (result not) all
```

i.e., negate the predicate then pass it into `all`).

See http://conal.net/blog/posts/semantic-editor-combinators

Comment: Is `(result.result) =  (.).(.)` the "boob operator"? Just trying to consolidate my knowledge.

Answer (score 5):

```
(.:) :: (r -> z) -> (a -> b -> r) -> a -> b -> z
(f .: g) x y = f (g x y)

foo :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Bool
foo = not .: any
```

`.:` is also available in `Data.Composition` from the `composition` package.

Comment: Nice! May I ask how did you find this function? I initially searched for `(a -> b) -> (c -> d -> a) -> c -> d -> b` on Hoogle but I didn't find anything.

Comment: You can find it on [FP Complete's Hoogle](https://www.fpcomplete.com/hoogle?q=%28a+-%3E+b%29+-%3E+%28c+-%3E+d+-%3E+a%29+-%3E+c+-%3E+d+-%3E+b&env=ghc-7.8-stable-14.09).  The haskell.org Hoogle searches a smaller set of packages by default.