# Haskell: Types of function composition not matching

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, function-composition, combinators

I am having some troubles with function composition and types.
I would like to compose `filter` (which returns a list) with `len`, which takes a list as an argument (technically a `Foldable` but I am simplifying here). 
Looking at the types everything is as expected:

```
> :t length
length :: Foldable t => t a -> Int

> :t filter
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

So now I would expect the type of `(len . filter)` to be

```
(length . filter) :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
```

while in reality is

```
> :t (length . filter)
(length . filter) :: Foldable ((->) [a]) => (a -> Bool) -> Int
```

So it seems I lost some arguments. Is it included in the the `Foldable` requirements in some way I am not understanding?

Note that everything works as expected if I do partial application:

```
> let myFilter = filter odd
> :t myFilter
myFilter :: Integral a => [a] -> [a]
> :t (length . myFilter)
(length . myFilter) :: Integral a => [a] -> Int
>  (length . myFilter) [1,2,3]
2
```

Comment: To get the type of composition that you are expecting, each function that you're composing should take 'one' argument. I put one in quotes because all functions take one argument. See more [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Currying)

Comment: Note that `(length . filter) x y` is `length (filter x) y` and not `length (filter x y)`. Also, `filter` is actually a  function taking _one_ argument `a->Bool` and returning a function `[a]->[a]` (recall currying), which the composition is trying to pass to `length`.

Comment: If something like `Num [a]` or anything with `(->)` turns up in a constraint (i.e. on the left of a `=>`), it's generally a sign that you've basically created a type error, but GHC is too polite to call it such because someone could _in principle_ define some ridiculous class instance that would make it legal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitions:

```
(.) :: (b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> c
filter ::  (m -> Bool) -> [m] -> [m]
length :: Foldable t => t n -> Int
```

What is `u`?

```
length . filter :: u
≡ (.) length filter :: u
```

Then we must solve `a, b, c, t, n`:

```
a -> b ~ (m -> Bool) -> [m] -> [m]
b -> c ~ Foldable t => t n -> Int
```

It follows:

```
a ~ m -> Bool
b ~ Foldable t => t n
b ~ [m] -> [m]
c ~ Int
```

Trivially:

```
a = m -> Bool
b = [m] -> [m]
c = Int
```

We have to solve `t, n` from `b ~ Foldable t => t n`, i.e. `[m] -> [m] ~ Foldable t => t n`.

```
t = ((->) [m])
n = [m]
```

Therefore, `t n = [m] -> [m]` which trivially unifies.

Summarising:

```
(.) :: Foldable ((->) [m]) =>
          (([m] -> [m]) -> Int)
       -> ((m -> Bool) -> [m] -> [m])
       -> (m -> Bool) -> Int

filter :: (m -> Bool) -> [m] -> [m]

length :: Foldable ((->) [m]) => ([m] -> [m]) -> Int

(.) length filter :: Foldable ((->) [m]) => (m -> Bool) -> Int
```

---

An easier way to understand why `length . filter` is not what you want is to look at the definition of `(.)`.

```
(.) g f x = g(f x)
```

Therefore:

```
(.) length filter
≡ \x -> length (filter x)
```

We know that `filter x` is not a list.

---

Pointless versions you may consider:

```
(length .) . filter

filter >=> return . length

(fmap.fmap) length filter

(id ~> id ~> length) filter -- [1]

filter $* id $$ id *$ length -- [2]

lurryA @N2 (length <$> (filter <$> _1 <*> _2)) -- [3]
```

1. [Control.Compose](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/TypeCompose-0.9.11/docs/Control-Compose.html)
2. [Data.Function.Meld](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-function-meld-0.1.1.0/docs/Data-Function-Meld.html)
3. [Data.Function.Tacit](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-function-tacit-0.1.0.0/docs/Data-Function-Tacit.html)

Comment: @WillNess thank-you for pointing out this mistake. I have made a correction. It should have read `filter >=> return . length`.

Answer (score 5):

The right composition would be:

```
(length .) . filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
```

which is equivalent to:

```
\pred xs -> length $ filter pred xs
```

as in:

```
\> let count = (length .) . filter
\> :type count
count :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> Int
\> count odd [1..3]
2
\> count even [1..3]
1
```

Comment: Just double checking I am following correctly:

`(length . ) . filter p  = length . (filter p)` and 

`length . (filter p) xs =  length ( (filter p) xs)`.

sorry for all the extra `()` but it's helpful for me to understand.

Comment: @meto `((f .) . g) x` is `f . (g x)` and `(f . (g x)) y` is `f (g x y)`

Answer (score 2):

Using ["three laws of operator sections"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13139969/currying-3-arguments-in-haskell/13147064#13147064), we have

```
((length .) . filter) x y =
 (length .) (filter x) y =
 (length . filter x) y =
 length (filter x y)
```

and

```
((length .) . filter) = 
  (.) (length .) filter =
  (.) ((.) length) filter =
  ((.) . (.)) length filter
```

The last bit, `((.).(.))`, is sometimes known as ["owl operator"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11006772/is-there-a-better-way-to-express-the-absolute-error-function-in-point-free-notat), also written as `.:` (`length .: filter`), or `fmap . fmap` (for functions, `fmap` is `(.)`).