# Haskell: a case of composition

Tags: haskell, function-composition

This is a useless case of concatenation via `foldl`, purely educational (for me):

```
foldl (\xs x -> xs ++ [x]) [1,2] [11,12,13]
[1,2,11,12,13]
```

Is there a way to pack it even tighter, using composition instead of the lambda?

Comment: `foldl ((. return) . (++))`. But it is better to use `flip (foldr (:))`.

Comment: Thanks! That much abour `foldr` I already figured out :) . I've been just grokking.

Comment: If you care about performance, know that `foldl` is quite inefficient, in general. `foldl'` is better, but it should only be used when the resulting type is small (e.g. a single `Int`). `foldr` is also OK, provided that the folding function is non-strict.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem If we are going to use `(++)` anyway, we can replace `foldl (\xs x -> ...)` with `(++)`, avoiding the folds.

Comment: Thanks, but no, I don't care for efficiency. It's just doodles, I'm studying.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Would you mind expounding a bit on this particular kind of composition?

Comment: You can [mechanically reduce](http://pointfree.io) any lambda expression to make it into pure composition. This usually involves `(.)`, `flip` to manage argument order, and `const` and `(<*>)` to ignore/duplicate arguments, respectively. It might help to add points to the function and simplify if you want to see how it works: `\hd tl -> ((. return) . (++)) hd tl = \hd tl -> ((. return) (hd ++)) tl = \hd tl -> ((hd ++) . return) tl = \hd tl -> hd ++ return tl = \hd tl -> hd ++ [tl]`. Forms like `(. x) . y` and `(x .) . y` compose functions with different numbers of arguments.

Comment: Kinda magnificent. I'll have to think a bit.

Comment: Somehow can't figure out the entity meant between the dot and the parenthesis. Must be another function, of course, but...

Comment: `(. x)` is an [operator section](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13147064/849891): a [partially applied operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37979558/849891), here `(.)`: `(. x) y = (y . x) = (y .) x = (.) y x`, by definition. it's just *syntax*. And `(. x) y z = (y . x) z = y (x z)`. Similarly, `((. x) . y) z w = (. x) (y z) w = ((y z) . x) w = (y z) (x w) = y z (x w)`. The manipulations of the equations are purely syntactical.

Comment: also, `(. x) y = (y . x) = (.) y x = flip (.) x y`, *hence* `(. x) = flip (.)` by *"eta contraction"*. Similarly  `(y .) = (.) y`. --- and, what you're asking about is known as *[tag:pointfree] programming*.

Comment: Thank you very much! It amounts to exhaustive answer. BTW, is there a way to partially apply to arguments not starting with the first one? Only third and fourth to a function of five args, for instance? Operator section rules suggest such possibility. Or is it just `flip` over two arguments? And how am I supposed to  declare this post answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a better readable summary extracted from the comments by [HTNW](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5684257/htnw) and [Will Ness](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849891/will-ness):

```
-- Reduction to poinfree
a = \xs x -> xs ++ [x]
b = \xs x -> xs ++ return x
c = \xs x -> ((xs ++) . return) x
d = \xs x -> ((. return) (xs ++)) x
e = \xs x -> ((. return) . (++)) xs x
```