# Eta reduction in haskell

Tags: haskell, reduction

I tried for a long time to reduct this function in haskell, I want to express for example:

```
mySum x y = x + y
mySum x y = (+) x y
mySum x = (+) x
mySum = (+) -- it's Messi's goal!
```

My function it a little more complex, but I really can't do it, I was looking out here and there, and I know there are some techniques, like modify the right side, and use `flip`. I tried and I got stuck here:

```
zipWith' :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
zipWith' f x y  = map  (uncurry f) (zip x y)
```

Steps:

```
zipWith' f x y  = map  (uncurry f) (zip x y) 
zipWith' f x y  = flip  map  (zip x y) (uncurry f)
zipWith' f x y  = flip  map  (zip x y) $ uncurry f
```

and then I don't know how to continue...

**I'm looking for an answer that could explain step by step how to achieve the "Messi's goal", I know is a lot to ask, so I will add as soon as I can a bounty to thank the effort**

Comment: You can't eta contract on the first argument, only on the last one, as you did for `mySum`.

Comment: [pointfree.io](http://pointfree.io/) says `zipWith' = (. zip) . (.) . map . uncurry`, by the way. Not too bad, but not exactly readable.

Comment: @chi thanks for the comment, I updated the answer, because I can't learn to do it myself again if I want to with just the right answer. But thanks!

Comment: That's why it's better way to define the other around, implement `zipWith` by hand and then simply do `zip = zipWith (,)`...

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29596285/point-free-problems-in-haskell/29596461#29596461) demonstrates some mechanical rules to follow when you want to do this

Comment: [`f (g x y) == ((f .) . g) x y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11009242/849891) is a standard tool to apply, easy to remember. ( also, `f (g x y z) = (((f .) .) . g) x y z` etc. ).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
zipWith' f x y = map (uncurry f) (zip x y)
```

Rewrite application to composition and eta-reduce:

```
-- \y -> let g = map (uncurry f); h = zip x in (g . h) y
-- let g = map (uncurry f); h = zip x in g . h

zipWith' f x = map (uncurry f) . zip x
```

Rewrite infix to prefix:

```
-- g . h = (.) g h

zipWith' f x = (.) (map (uncurry f)) (zip x)
```

Rewrite application to composition and eta-reduce:

```
-- \x -> let g = (.) (map (uncurry f)); h = zip in (g . h) x
-- let g = (.) (map (uncurry f)); h = zip in g . h

zipWith' f = (.) (map (uncurry f)) . zip
```

Rewrite infix to prefix:

```
-- g . h = (.) g h

zipWith' f = (.) ((.) (map (uncurry f))) zip
```

Use `flip` to move `f` to the right-hand side:

```
-- flip f x y = f y x

zipWith' f = flip (.) zip ((.) (map (uncurry f)))
```

Rewrite application to composition:

```
-- g (h (i x)) = (g . h . i) x

zipWith' f = flip (.) zip (((.) . map . uncurry) f)
```

Rewrite application to composition and eta-reduce:

```
-- \f -> let g = flip (.) zip; h = (.) . map . uncurry in (g . h) f
-- let g = flip (.) zip; h = (.) . map . uncurry in g . h

zipWith' = (flip (.) zip) . ((.) . map . uncurry)
```

Remove redundant parentheses:

```
zipWith' = flip (.) zip . (.) . map . uncurry
```

And simplify to infix if you like:

```
zipWith' = (. zip) . (.) . map . uncurry
```

This result isn’t very readable, though.

---

Often when writing *fully* point-free code, you want to take advantage of the `->` applicative and arrow combinators from `Control.Arrow`. Rather than trying to write a function like `\ f x y -> ...`, you can start by grouping the arguments into tuples to make them easier to rearrange and pipe around. In this case I’ll use `\ (f, (x, y)) -> ...`

```
\ (f, (x, y)) -> map (uncurry f) (zip x y)
```

We can eliminate the unpacking of `(x, y)` by applying `uncurry` to `zip`:

```
\ (f, (x, y)) -> map (uncurry f) (uncurry zip (x, y))
\ (f, xy) -> map (uncurry f) (uncurry zip xy)
```

Now we have a simple case: applying two functions (`uncurry` and `uncurry zip`) to two arguments (`f` and `xy`), then combining the results (with `map`). For this we can use the `***` combinator from `Control.Arrow`, of type:

```
(***) :: Arrow a => a b c -> a b' c' -> a (b, b') (c, c')
```

Specialised to functions, that’s:

```
(***) @(->) :: (b -> c) -> (b' -> c') -> (b, b') -> (c, c')
```

This just lets us apply a function to each element of a pair. Perfect!

```
uncurry *** uncurry zip
  :: (a -> b -> c, ([x], [y])) -> ((a, b) -> c, [(x, y)])
```

You can think of `uncurry f` as combining the elements of a pair using the function `f`. So here we can combine the results using `uncurry map`:

```
uncurry map . (uncurry *** uncurry zip)
  :: (a -> b -> c, ([a], [b])) -> [c]
```

And you can think of `curry` as turning a function on tuples into a multi-argument function. Here we have two levels of tuples, the outer `(f, xy)` and the inner `(x, y)`. We can unpack the outer one with `curry`:

```
curry $ uncurry map . (uncurry *** uncurry zip)
  :: (a -> b -> c) -> ([a], [b]) -> [c]
```

Now, you can think of `fmap f` in the `->` applicative as “skipping over” the first argument:

```
fmap @((->) _) :: (a -> b) -> (t -> a) -> t -> b
```

So we can unpack the second tuple using `fmap curry`:

```
fmap curry $ curry $ uncurry map . (uncurry *** uncurry zip)
  :: (a -> b -> c) -> [a] -> [b] -> [c]
```

And we’re done! Or not quite. When writing point-free code, it pays to break things out into many small reusable functions with clearer names, for example:

```
zipWith' = untuple2 $ combineWith map apply zipped
  where
    untuple2 = fmap curry . curry
    combineWith f g h = uncurry f . (g *** h)
    apply = uncurry
    zipped = uncurry zip
```

---

However, while knowing these techniques is useful, all this is just unproductive trickery that’s easy to get lost in. Most of the time, you should only use point-free style in Haskell when it’s a clear win for readability, and neither of these results is clearer than the simple original version:

```
zipWith' f x y = map (uncurry f) (zip x y)
```

Or a *partially* point-free version:

```
zipWith' f = map (uncurry f) .: zip
  where (.:) = (.) . (.)
```

Comment: Rhetorical question: do you have to work your way through all the unproductive stuff in order to realize what is important or simple?

Comment: @AndreiBozantan: If you do it once, you might develop a better sense of how and when to avoid doing it again :)